# select count (distinct) returning incorrect count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a code that will summarise a list of clients based on age categories. I have the client ID and their ages, and am using a CASE WHEN to group the ages into buckets, then trying to count the client ids in each of those buckets.

For info - the Assisted Date field is just the date on which the client was served and this is just included in my testing to keep the results small - so I'm just focusing on Feb 2019 services that aren't Assessments; and the SIR ID is the location at which the service was provided.

```
select distinct 
    CASE
        when CD.Age between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
        when CD.Age between 6 and 11 then '6-11'
        when CD.Age between 12 and 14 then '12-14'
        when CD.Age between 15 and 17 then '15-17'
        when CD.Age between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
        when CD.Age between 25 and 54 then '25-54'
        when CD.Age between 55 and 64 then '55-64'
        when CD.Age > 65 then '65+'
        else 'Unknown'
    END AS Age_Group, 
count(distinct AP.Source_Individual_ID) as "Count"
from dm.Assistance_Provided AP, rpt.ClientsDemographics CD
        where CD.Source_Individual_ID = AP.Source_Individual_ID
        and AP.SIR_ID = '1909'
        and AP.Service_Provided <> 'Assessment'
        and year(AP.Assisted_Date) = '2019'
        and month(AP.Assisted_Date) = 2
group by CD.Age
```

If I run the code excluding the count(distinct) I end up with 17 rows of data. The 17 clients are all aged between 18-24 so the Age-Group for all clients come back as 18-24. So the Case When appears to be operating correctly.

However, if I run the code with the count(distinct), I end up with 3 rows of data. the Age Group 18-24 is listed 3 times and the Count as 2, 4, and 5 respectively for the 3 lines. I definitely have 17 different IDs in the list, but for some reason this is being reduced to a total of 11 when I add the count(distinct).

I've also tried removing the distinct from the select i.e. so

```
select 
    CASE
        when CD.Age between ....
```

If I do that I get 5 rows - still all with age group 18-24, but then with 2,4,5,4,2 respectively - so then back to my total of 17. But I'm not sure why I'm not just getting one line back : Age Group: 18-24; Count: 17

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this means you have only 3 distinct individual_id s in your AP table. the join will probably bring more IDs from other table but your AP contains only 3 distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your case statement in your `group by`. As it is, since you `group by CD.Age` it will write a single row for every distinct age. In other words if you have two rows with `Age =  12` and one row with `Age = 13` you'll get two rows, both with `12-14` as their age group, but with a count of `2` for the first and `1` for the second. To make it more confusing, if you only had one row each, then because both rows are the same and you have the `distinct` clause it would only return 1 row with a count of 1.

If you put your case statement into the group by, then it will group by each distinct `Age_Group` instead. i.e., it does the case transformation first, then groups by it.

So try:

```
select 
    CASE
        when CD.Age between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
        when CD.Age between 6 and 11 then '6-11'
        when CD.Age between 12 and 14 then '12-14'
        when CD.Age between 15 and 17 then '15-17'
        when CD.Age between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
        when CD.Age between 25 and 54 then '25-54'
        when CD.Age between 55 and 64 then '55-64'
        when CD.Age > 65 then '65+'
        else 'Unknown'
    END AS Age_Group, 
count(distinct AP.Source_Individual_ID) as "Number of Clients Assisted"
from dm.Assistance_Provided AP, rpt.ClientsDemographics CD
        where CD.Source_Individual_ID = AP.Source_Individual_ID
        and AP.SIR_ID = '1909'
        and AP.Service_Provided <> 'Assessment'
        and year(AP.Assisted_Date) = '2019'
        and month(AP.Assisted_Date) = 2
group by CASE
        when CD.Age between 0 and 5 then '0-5'
        when CD.Age between 6 and 11 then '6-11'
        when CD.Age between 12 and 14 then '12-14'
        when CD.Age between 15 and 17 then '15-17'
        when CD.Age between 18 and 24 then '18-24'
        when CD.Age between 25 and 54 then '25-54'
        when CD.Age between 55 and 64 then '55-64'
        when CD.Age > 65 then '65+'
        else 'Unknown'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you should actually be aggregating by `Source_Individual`, and then taking conditional counts everywhere:

```
SELECT
    CD.Source_Individual_ID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN 1 END) AS [0-5],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN 1 END) AS [6-11],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 12 AND 14 THEN 1 END) AS [12-14],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 15 AND 17 THEN 1 END) AS [15-17],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN 1 END) AS [18-24],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 25 AND 54 THEN 1 END) AS [25-54],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age BETWEEN 55 AND 64 THEN 1 END) AS [55-64]
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CD.Age > 65 THEN 1 END) AS [65+],
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of Clients Assisted]
FROM dm.Assistance_Provided AP 
INNER JOIN rpt.ClientsDemographics CD
    ON CD.Source_Individual_ID = AP.Source_Individual_ID
WHERE
    AP.SIR_ID = '1909' AND
    AP.Service_Provided <> 'Assessment' AND
    YEAR(AP.Assisted_Date) = 2019 AND
    MONTH(AP.Assisted_Date) = 2
GROUP BY
    CD.Source_Individual_ID;
```

Note that I have rewritten your query to use explicit, modern, inner joins, rather than the implicit joins you were using.

Comment: Thanks so much both! These are very helpful answers.